# Django: Is it possible to run django without Nginx, gunicorn?

Tags: django, nginx, portforwarding

What I want to do is to run my `django` project on my desktop(`Ubuntu 16.04`) computer at my home.

I have a `Wi-Fi-router` and use `port-forwarding` function to access other computer at my home by ssh. It also supports one free DDNS so I have a my own domain. Let say domain name is `THIS_IS_MY_DOMAIN`

This is my idea :

- Run `django` on my desktop

  - Set `DEBUG=False, ALLOWED_HOST=["*",]` in `settings.py`
  - Run django by `python super_crawler/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8002`
  - Port-forwarding on my Router : 8002(external) -> 8002(internal)

When I run my django application, it shows like this in terminal:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8002
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
January 19, 2018 - 17:38:03
Django version 1.11.8, using settings 'config.settings.production'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8002/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Now I access some pages via other computer's browser with other network(from outside), and it shows like this:

1. `THIS_IS_MY_DOMAIN:8002/` 
   => `Not Found. The requested URL / was not found on this server.`
2. `THIS_IS_MY_DOMAIN:8002/admin/`
   => `Server Error (500)`

On my desktop, `Nginx` was off.

I wonder whether I can run django **ON MY DESKTOP** in any other way.

Must I use `nginx`, `gunicorn`?

**Edit**
Actually if I set `DEBUG=True`, it works like a charm. But problem is that if I set `DEBUG=True`, it could occurs memory leak. That's why I want to run django in production mode.

Comment: It should work fine. Are you sure you set the value of `ALLOWED_HOSTS` with a final `s`?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work..

Comment: Well then check your logs to find the content of the error 500.

Comment: @SébastienDeprez logs? Where I can find logs?

Comment: It depends on your configuration: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/logging/. Usually when `DEBUG=False`, the logs are written to a file somewhere on your computer.

Comment: @SébastienDeprez As I know of, `django` send error log email to `superuser` but it didn't.... seems strange.. When I made a super user by `python manage.py createsuperuser`, I surely type my email address.....

Comment: You should not do this. The `manage.py runserver` command is not meant to be used in production, you should not expose it to the public internet with port forwarding. You don't have to use Nginx + gunicorn - Apache + modwsgi is another [well documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) approach.

Comment: @Alasdair But all I want to do is just access admin page. My application doesn't serve anything as a web. All tasks are performed in low level....

Comment: It doesn’t matter what the content of your site is. The point is that the `runserver` command isn’t designed to be publicly accessible. It’s insecure.